# When will rethinkdb return a cursor

Tags: rethinkdb

I notice that `r.table('xxx')` not always return a `cursor` but also sometimes just return `docs` directly

1. Is the `cursor` client side implementation only or there are some special things `server` did to perform queries associate with a `cursor`?
2. If it has somethings related to `server`, what is it and when will I receive a `cursor`

> For example I specify result offset and size with `skip` and `limit` in the query. Will server return a `cursor` or just result `docs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A driver returns a cursor when the query returns a stream.

Basically when the server produces a stream (a sequence that is lazily computed), the driver will return a cursor. As you fetch rows from the cursor, the server will compute more elements in the sequence.

For example, when you run `r.table('xxx')`, you will get back a cursor. The server will load the documents from disk as you request them with the driver.

In the JavaScript driver, when a query return an array, the driver will sneak an object that mimics the cursor interface between the arrray itself and Array.prototype.
So if `query.run(...)` returns a sequence, you can just do

```
query.run(connection).then(function(result) {
    return result.toArray()
}).then(function(result) {
    // do something with result
}).error(function(err) {
    // handle err
})
```

Basically if you don't want to think if you are getting back a cursor or an array, you can just consider that it's a cursor.

You can read more about stream/cursor here:
http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/data-types/

Comment: If I want to write a driver? How could I tell which response is cursor ? according to `SUCCESS_PARTIAL` response type ? When will the server return this type(I mean is there a threshold of result doc count)

Comment: If you get a SUCCESS_PARTIAL, it means that the driver is supposed to send back a cursor. If you get a SUCCESS_COMPLETE, you should also return a cursor. If you get back an array, the response type will be SUCCESS_ATOM.

Comment: Is it OK when I receive a `SUCCESS_SEQUENCE` and not send the `STOP` query?

Comment: Yes it's ok. A `STOP` query should be sent only to close a cursor that hasn't retrieved all his data yet.