# Getting "Expected Object, got Boolean" after removing a then() function

Tags: javascript, express, rethinkdb

This following is a database query (Express + [RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/))...

```
app.get('/projects', function(req, res) {
  r.db("test").table("feeds").run(rdb)
    .finally(function() { rdb.close()
  }).then(function(cursor) {
    return cursor.toArray()
  }).then(function(output) {
    res.send(output)
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log("Error:", err)
  })
})
```

...outputs: `[Object, Object]`

I wanted to remove one step (a `then()`) so I wrote:

```
app.get('/projects', function(req, res) {
  r.db("test").table("feeds").run(rdb)
    .finally(function() { rdb.close()
  }).then(function(cursor) {
    res.send(cursor.toArray())
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log("Error:", err)
  })
})
```

But now I'm getting a boolean instead of an array of objects:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed. Expected Object, got Boolean.
```

What's the part that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.toArray()` is not a synchronous operation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375082/when-will-rethinkdb-return-a-cursor) might give some insight. If you use the official driver, you will have to turn the cursor into an array as you did in your first example.

I personally use [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash) to avoid having to do it manually each time.